# I am using appendChild in a 'contact; form to print a nice message upon submission, but the message disappears immediately

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a very basic 'contact us' form, and I want to have a little "Thanks for your feedback" message appear on the page (not as an alert), upon successful form validation. The problem is, I hit the submit button, and the thankyou message appears for a split second and then disappears.

Code:

```
window.onload = init;

function init() 
{
document.getElementById("contactForm").onsubmit=validate;
}

function validate()
{
//if statements to appear here returning false if any conditions are met
addMessage();
return true;
}

function addMessage()
{
var p = document.getElementById("content");
var l = document.createElement("p");
var m = document.createTextNode("Thanks for your message!");

l.appendChild(m);
p.appendChild(l);   
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am pretty new to javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `true` after calling `addMessage()`, so the message is displayed and then the form is submitted immediately.

If you want to prevent immediate form submission, you can either use standard `alert()` (it waits for user to press OK button) or prevent form submission by returning false and then submitting the form explicitly by calling `form.submit()` method when user clicks some button after he has read the message.

Actually, message like "Thanks for your message!" should be displayed on target page specified in `action` attribute of the form and loaded after form is already sent. It's not a good idea to say something that assumes the form is sent while it is not yet.

Comment: So there's no way I can have the function display the message then return true, without the message disappearing? I would like the message to persist until the page is reloaded.

Comment: Form submission by nature involves loading another page or reloading same page (depending on what is specified in `action` attribute of form).

Comment: @Cam - The message *will* persist until the page is reloaded: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GvH75/).  Your page must just be reloading too fast for you to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Both Firefox 15 and IE 9 update the DOM before submitting the form, so I can't see it's an issue. But anyhow, you can delay submission by calling it from *setTimeout*, that way it's pretty much guaranteed that the DOM will update to display the message, then the form will be submitted, e.g.

```
<script>
function validate(form) {

  var formValid = false;

  /* validatation stuff, set formValid to appropriate value, assume passed */

  formValid = true;

  if (formValid) {

    // Show message
    document.getElementById('message').style.display = '';

    // Delay submit until after message displayed
    setTimeout(function(){form.submit()}, 10);

    // Stop form submitting immediately
    return false;

  } else {

    /* form isn't valid, do whatever and cancel submission */
    return false;
  }
}
</script>

<span id="message" style="display: none">Success!!</span>
<form onsubmit="return validate(this);">
  <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Note that calling the form's submit method doesn't dispatch a sumbit event, so the submit handler isn't called again. This is contrary to the DOM 2 HTML standard, but browsers never followed it anyway.

It's been changed in the new "living" HTML specification so that a submit event must not be dispatched if submission is from the form's submit method.